# Virtualising Aptana 3.0.4 with Microsoft App-V 4.6SP1

Tags: firefox, virtual

We have successfully virtualised over 100 applications using Microsoft App-V 4.6 SP1, but are experiencing difficulties sequencing Aptana Studio 3.0.4...

We would choose to not virtualise it but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Let me explain...

Environment:

- Target machines: Windows 7 x64
- Browser: Firefox 5.0.1 (virtualised into it's own directory)
- Sequencer machine: Windows 7 x86 (Can be used to virtualise 32bit apps for x64 platform)
- Virtual App: Microsoft App-V 4.6SP1

  1. We fire up the Microsoft App-V sequencing / virtualisation wizard and point to the source .gz.exe installer for portable git. (we added the .exe to the .gz extension)
  2. We choose to install the portable GIT into the virtual directory of Q:\Aptana.304
  3. After the files extract we run the AptanaStudio 3.0.4 install and also install this to Q:\Aptana.304
  4. We then fire up AptanaStudio 3.0.4 whilst it's int he sequencer and it asks for the GIT.exe (We're presuming it's hardcoded to look in a particular directory?), so we point it to Q:\Aptana.304\bin\git.exe
  5. We then create a new web project and it asks for the location of Firefox for debugging puposes. So we point Aptana to Q:\firefox.501\firefox.exe
  6. We then close Aptana, create another web project and it seems to work okay.
  7. So we finish up and stream the virtualised Aptana and Git to the client...

A. The client fires up Aptana and immediately it asks for GIT.exe. So we try to re-point it to Q:\Aptana.304\bin\git.exe, but the bin directory is now empty!? *

B. We skip past the git.exe requirement and try to create a web project and guess what, yep - it' asks for firefox.exe. So we re-point it to Q:\firefox.501\firefox.exe AGAIN.

So we try and sequence the application again, this time we include the '%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\' directory into the sequencer (it was previously excluded) and try the above steps again.

Unfortunately we experience the same problems.

For the next atempt I try and pre-populate the git environment both the virtual sequencing machine and the physcial machines by installing portable git into it's default directory:

'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git'

This time when we fire up Aptana it no longer complains about the missing GIT.exe but we sstill have to point it to firefox.exe

Then we run into another problem:

When opening up the terminal in Aptana it reads:

*rm: cannot unlink `/etc/msys-1.0.dll.md5': Permission denied
ERROR: Your msys-1.0.dll is out-of-date!*

At this point we begin to kind of give up on and decide to see if we can silently install Aptana without virtualising it, but wait...

A rule of virtualising pops up: Virtual applications can see physical applications and other virtual applications (as they are in the same virtual world / bubble), but physical applications **can't** see the virtual applications.

So even if we installed Aptana and git *physically* on the machine, Aptana would not be able to see the virtualised firefox.exe

And there is no way on the planet that I am going to undo my virtual applications because we can't get Aptana to play ball.

So I wonder if someone could help us to get Aptana and GIT.exe working in a virtual environment.

It seems as if the settings for Aptana (even though tested during the sequencing stage) do not carry down to the target machine.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

- Our virtual applications directory (Q:) is hidden from the user by default, but there's a trick in App-V whereby we can point the app to \127.0.0.1\q$\ instead of Q:\appname\

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried one of the Application compatability tools? I work for Changebase we have a free lite version of our tool AOK. Which you can download to look at the App Compat issues you are having. http://www.changebase.com/AOKLite/aoklite.aspx.